# rewrite a matrix with maximum values using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, programming

Given a matrix A, Write a Matlab function that keeps the maximum of each row and set all the
other elements to zero.

I've started the code but I didn't know how to continue. Can anyone help me?

function B=maxmatr(A)

A=input("Enter a Matrix :");

[r, c]=size(A);

for i=1:r

```
a(i)=max(A, [], 2);

for j=1:c

    B(i,j)=
```

Comment: $$r=3;c=4;A=rand(r,c);$$ $$[M,Ind]=max(A');$$ $$B=zeros(r,c);$$ $$for \ i=1:r;B(i,Ind(i))=M(i);end;$$ Please note that I have used in the second line the feature of "max" function applied to the transpose of A that allows to keep track of indices where the maxima occurs.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you soo much, the code works normally, one last question on different topic. If I want to calculate a given function f(x) for x from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.1, how one can do it?

Comment: Assume that you have taken care to define for example (in an "anonymous way") function f by : f=@(x)(x.^2) (with a point) and not f=@(x)(x^2), then you can make the call f(0:0.1:1) for that.

Comment: @JeanMarie When I define the following function $$f(x)=\dfrac{xcos(x)}{(x^2+1)(x+2)}$$ in matlab as $$f=@(x)((x.*cos x.)/((x.^2+1)*(x+2)))$$ I got and error, what you think the mistake is?

Comment: Because the point should be moved after the closing parenthesis, just before the divide symbol, like this `f=@(x)((x.*cos(x))./((x.^2+1)*(x+2)))`

Comment: Many thanks, it worked.